# How to force malloc to return a 32 bits like pointer on a 64 bits system?

Tags: linux, malloc, x86-64, glibc, 32-bit

I have a bug in a program so that it works fine on 32 bits but works only randomly on 64 bits because of 32 bits pointer truncation somewhere in the program.

The reason is a pointer turns to NULL if it malloc returns a memory address with a bit set in the upper 32 bits on pointer allocation.

So I found the pointer which triggers the segfault. But it’s not a program where I got involved (I’m a user not a developer) and there’s no compiler warnings at all.

So instead of taking time I don´t have, how to just make sure malloc returns a value which can be used in 32 bits mode?

Comment: There are huge performance benefits from using full 64 bits in the case of this program, so I’d really like not to use x32.

Comment: What's wrong with [the x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) for your use-case?  32-bit pointers in long mode sounds like exactly what you need, unless you also `mmap` directly to make use of the extra address space, even if you have `malloc` using `mmap(MAP_32BIT)`?  Or the program fails to take advantage of 64-bit registers if `long` is a 32-bit type?  Or did you actually mean i386, not x32?

Comment: @PeterCordes the problem is 32 bits intensive maths and 32 bits intensive disc access.

Comment: So how does x86-64 with 64-bit pointers help in a way that x32 (ILP32 in 64-bit mode) doesn't?  Have you actually tried `gcc -mx32 -O3 -march=native`?  Note `-mx32` not `-m32`.

Comment: @PeterCordes 64 bits maths and 64 bits disc access system calls. And yes I did. I also have a version of the Intel compiler which doesn t support x32. So things can really get faster through the Intel proprietary autopar.

Comment: You're not reading what I'm writing.  x32 is 64-bit mode.  Go read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI.  It's an ILP32 ABI for 64-bit mode x86-64.  uint64_t fits in a single register in x32.  It might be *exactly* what you need if you have code that's not 64-bit clean for pointers, but uses lots of 64-bit integer math.  (edit in response to your comment edit: unless your compiler doesn't support x32, that's a problem.)  If your compiler doesn't support x32, then obviously you haven't tried it...  So I think you were confusing x32 (`-mx32`) with crappy old i386 32-bit code (`-m32`)

Comment: @PeterCordes yes I read x32 is more general purpose registers than plain i686 and also offer instructions not availaible for i686. And even if it were 64 bits, it s still single threaded because of gcc whereas Intel can perform more powerfull compile optimizations (I don t have the svml runtime for x32). **I mean I am stuck at gcc for x32 mode**.

Comment: x32 is exactly like regular `-m64` except that pointers, `size_t`, and `long` are 32-bit types.  It *is* 64-bit.  So the actual obstacle is that you don't have an x32 SVML.  I agree that's a showstopper, but please stop being wrong about x32 by saying things like "even if it were 64 bits".  Look at the identical asm you get for `uint64_t` a+b from ICC16 and later: https://godbolt.org/z/j8gIuh.  Intel's compiler *does* support x32, and SVML is available for x32 ([or at least it was as of version 16.0](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/628948)), so hopefully you can just go download it.

Comment: Also see [How to use 32-bit pointers in 64-bit application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10083744/608639) and [Can you enter x64 32-bit “long compatibility sub-mode” outside of kernel mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12716419/608639) I _thought_ ICC allows you to effectively use a 32-bit address space for 64-bit programs, but I can't find the reference at the moment. On Windows I believe Intel provides a driver for it. Otherwise Peter's [x32 suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7635013/608639) is probably the best option you have.

Comment: @user2284570 - Another option is, link to the program's {GitHub|BitBucket|etc} and point to the problem. Maybe someone here can drop a patch for you.

Comment: @jww it’s a zip file on an invite only forum. I couldn't even point out the problem. icc allows building for x32 but I don’t just don’t have Intel runtime libraries for x32 with my version (I don’t know where to download them).

Comment: @PeterCordes SVML is supportted on x32 but I simply don’t have the x32 version for linking and I don’t know where to download it.

Comment: You might want to post on the Intel forums to ask where you can download SVML for x32.  I googled a bit, but other than that x32 psABI page for ICC 16.0, which seems to be part of some embedded / bi-endian thing, I didn't find anything by googling.

Comment: @PeterCordes so I simply admit that allocating a 32 bits pointer is required because 64 bits is the only way forward. A pointer which can be passed to `free()` of course.

Comment: Intel's compilers clearly do support `-mx32`, so it's certainly worth asking on Intel's forums about libraries for it.  Maybe you'll hear back before you finish modifying `tcmalloc` to use `MAP_32BIT`.  Or take your pick, there are many 3rd-party drop-in malloc replacements and I have no idea if tcmalloc is easier to modify than others.
 [Is there any better implementation than malloc/calloc for allocating memory in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8892953) lists some

Comment: @PeterCordes turns out I m having an additionnal problem https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/620680 about using x32 at all.

Answer (score 3):

Best option: get the author of this buggy program to fix their code to be 64-bit clean, or use [Linux's x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) (`gcc -mx32`) for 64-bit registers but 32-bit pointers.

---

**AFAIK, there's no simple way to do exactly what you're asking with regular glibc malloc**.  Replacing `malloc`/`free` with  `mmap(MAP_32BIT)` would probably work, but be horrible for small allocations because it can only allocate in 4k chunks.
`mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_32BIT, -1, 0)` / `munmap`.  It's not a drop-in replacement because some code probably needs pointers that are compatible with `free`.

Or if you can find a custom `malloc` that uses `MAP_32BIT` as a workaround for buggy software that isn't 64-bit clean, you could use that as a drop-in replacement.  **Or modifying a custom-malloc library like `tcmalloc` to add `MAP_32BIT` might be a lot easier than building a whole custom glibc.**

@Basile Starynkevitch suggests maybe using `mmap(MAP_FIXED|MAP_NORESERVE)` to map a huge range so all that's left is the low 32 bits.  (Then never touch this mapping).   [The range of virtual memory address in userspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885905/the-range-of-virtual-memory-address-in-userspace/30886061#30886061)  But that will only work if done before any libraries are loaded at high addresses ([How to limit a 64-bit process address space to less than 4G?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388208/how-to-limit-a-64-bit-process-address-space-to-less-than-4g) suggests a possible way to prelink to get libraries loaded to low addresses).

`MAP_FIXED` will replace existing mappings in the range, so probably you want to omit MAP_FIXED and just give a non-NULL hint address and check that it mapped at the address you requested.

---

**If you have code that's not 64-bit clean for pointers, but you still want to take advantage of 64-bit registers for efficient `[u]int64_t`, Linux's x32 ABI might be exactly what you need.**

[x32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) is an ILP32 ABI for x86-64 long mode, so pointers, `size_t`, and `long` are 32-bit types, but 64-bit integer types like **`long long` and `uint64_t` can use 64-bit registers**.  The CPU is running in 64-bit long mode, and the ABI uses the same efficient register-args calling convention as the regular x86-64 System V ABI.

**Do *not* confuse x32 with the legacy 32-bit code i386 ABI**.  They're totally unrelated.  x32 is a minor modification to the regular x86-64 ABI.

The usual reason for using x32 is a smaller cache footprint with pointer-heavy data structures, increasing cache hits and saving memory bandwidth.

> I don't have the Intel SVML runtime for x32

**Intel's compiler and libraries including SVML support x32 from version 16.0 onward, see [Intel's x32 psABI Support page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/628948)**.  If you have a version older than 16.0, this might be a good reason to upgrade.

(That page seems to say OpenMP might not be supported on x32, at least in version 16.0.  That would be a problem if I'm reading that right.  Current is 19.01, maybe it's working now.)

Notice that the asm output for a function that adds two `uint64_t` args is identical for `icc -O3 -mx32` and `icc -O3 -m64`, both using `add rdi, rsi` / `mov rax,rdi`.  (While ICC is good at auto-vectorizing and auto-parallelizing, apparently it's bad at spotting `lea rax, [rdi+rsi]` as a peephole optimization, and when using `mov` doesn't follow its own optimization-manual advice to copy first and then destroy the copy for [more efficient mov-elimination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all/44193770#44193770).)

But anyway, current versions of Intel's compiler itself definitely support x32; the asm output from C++ shows that `uint64_t` is `unsigned long long` instead of `unsigned long`.

---

#### Getting GCC to use SVML:

GCC has a `-mveclibabi=svml` option which lets it auto-vectorize using SVML functions.  So if x32 ICC has a problem using OpenMP to auto-parallelize, you could try GCC.

`gcc -fopenmp -O3 -ffast-math -march=native -mveclibabi=svml` should probably be good.  (`-ffast-math` is similar to what ICC enables by default.)

---

### Getting regular 64-bit `malloc` to return 32-bit pointers

Related: an OS X version of the question: [How to 'malloc' within first 4GB on x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661393/how-to-malloc-within-first-4gb-on-x86-64) (no easy way there either).

I don't think glibc malloc has an option for this.

It would be possible to build your own glibc with a minor change, if you can find the `mmap` call that `malloc` uses to get new pages from the OS, and add the [`MAP_32BIT`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) flag to it.

> Put the mapping into the first 2 Gigabytes of the process
> address space.  This flag is supported only on x86-64, for
> 64-bit programs.  It was added to allow thread stacks to be
> allocated somewhere in the first 2 GB of memory, so as to
> improve context-switch performance on some early 64-bit
> processors

If you compile a non-PIE executable, the break should be in the low 32 already, so you shouldn't need to stop glibc from using `brk()` for small allocations.

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Malloc-Tunable-Parameters.html lists the things you can set with a `mallopt` call, or environment variables, e.g. `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD`.  Setting that to 4k would get glibc to always use mmap for allocations of that size or larger.  But there's no 32-bit option.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning... *"The `MAP_32BIT` flag is ignored when `MAP_FIXED` is set"* per [`mmap(2)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).

Comment: @jww: Makes sense, the kernel doesn't make any choices about where to allocate in that case.  MAP_FIXED disables the fallback to kernel-chosen address if the hint address would cause a collision with existing mappings.  So the only way it could apply would be to return an error if passed a fixed address outside the low 32.  (Or if the *end* of the mapping extended outside the low 32).

Comment: What I’m looking for is rather for icc to not use SVML. But intensive optimizations turns on SVML only code generation.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is supposed to support this using various [personality flags](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html): `ADDR_LIMIT_32BIT`, `ADDR_LIMIT_3GB`, `PER_LINUX32`, `PER_LINUX32_3GB`, `PER_LINUX_32BIT`.  The `setarch linux32 -B` command calls `personality(PER_LINUX32|ADDR_LIMIT_32BIT)`, but this request is ignored by the kernel on x86-64:

```
$ setarch x86_64 -B grep stack /proc/self/maps  
7fff38461000-7fff38482000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
```

I think this was only implemented for other 64-bit architectures to support porting 32-bit software with pointer truncation problems.

Comment: Hemm yes, but my primary objective is to get the program working fast instead of taking days without taking a lot time. I fear creating an allocator would consume more time than fixing the actual error.

Comment: Thanks for posting this; I'd wondered if that `personality` stuff did anything, and what it was for!  Some other 64-bit ISAs, like MIPS, extend to 64-bit *without* introducing a new mode.  It would make a lot more sense there to be sure to distinguish whether user-space is running code that's 64-bit-aware or not, because the kernel *doesn't* need to do an equivalent of x86's using a different CS value to select 32 or 64-bit mode for user-space.

Comment: (On MIPS, they extended the ISA so add/sub etc. naturally keep register values sign-extended to 64-bit, adding `dadd` double-word add instructions.  Shift instructions do explicitly sign-extend their 32-bit result to 64 bits.  See [MOVZX missing 32 bit register to 64 bit register](//stackoverflow.com/q/51387571) for some comparison between MIPS64 and x86-64, it's an interesting ISA design choice, especially given that MIPS had so much opcode coding space left to add doubleword versions of many instructions.  But I think AMD64 is a better choice: implicit zero extension is handy.)

Comment: @user2284570 The problem is that without kernel help, global variables in shared objects will be mapped high in the address space. You can force heap addresses to the lower 4 GiB with a custom allocator, but the addresses of global variables will not be affected by this.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer glibc is the only shared object and is used for performing console writing and ioctls and fread/fwrite outside memory management.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer things changed a bit with newer Macintosh . Does aarch64 supports this?